# Postgresql 13 Stored Procedure to Ingest Object and Event Logs Slows Down over time. Where to look?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I am still learning all the ropes to Postgresql13 and partitioning within.  I am trying to convert from SQL Server and we have reached a point where the Ingest Stored procedure for Objects (Inserts and Updates) and Events (Inserts) slows downs after a minutes of being fed from a service.  I have bunch of timing lines that show me the commands that slow down the most.   When I first start, these commands take .0x seconds.  5 minutes later they take .3 seconds,  5 minutes later 1.x, 10 minutes 3.x, etc. after a few hours 20-30 seconds.

1. Is there a common pitfall where you see this issue?   Any with temp tables?
2. If not, what can I provide you that would help.   Do you need the specific commands, the entire sproc, the table structures including partitions and indexes
3. service is windows .net multithreaded using Npgsql  Any pitfalls there that often cause degradation?

Comment: It would be helpful to know 1) The SQL statements that make up a single database transaction (is all that a single transaction) 2) `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for a fast and a slow `INSERT` (perhaps collected with auto_explain)

Comment: Here is pseudo design. Open to changing.  Just starting with what has worked well in SQL Server.  1 stays quick enough  2 and 3 degrade too molasses.
1) Convert Text to XML, Create-Truncate Temp Table, Load XML into Temp Tables
2) Inserts and Prep for Updates  3) Final Updates 

Each section has a few timing inserts followed by commits so multiple DB Transactions (I think).   I will try to figure out best way to get EXPLAINs to you.

Comment: FYI, learning, and liking Auto_Explain.  Running with this new insight and will let you know if sucessful or I need help still.

Comment: auto_explain has helped me help myself, thank you!!   So at same time each of the service thread's calls of stored procedure are running quite slow, when I make that call from pgAdmin, even with a large xml, they run fast....  So It can't be the sql by itself.  Each of my temp tables have a Create if not exists at the beginning of the sproc, then truncate immediately afterwards.  Is there any clean up that should be dones besides those???

Comment: I still have only a very vague idea of what you are doing - some code can tell more than a 1000 words. If you have a lot of `UPDATE`s in a single transaction, perhaps your table statistics get outdated, or you end up with lots of dead index entries that cannot get cleaned up. With a lot of `INSERT`s in a single transaction, perhaps there is some issue with the free space map. All wild guesses, since you don't provide any hard data.